# Lauching 2d block of threads in Cuda crashes

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, particle-system

I am building a n-body simulation, using CUDA to increase performance.  I am currently working on further parallelizing the system so each interaction between particles runs on a seperate thread.  This reduces the theoretical complexity to 1 only limited by the speed of the GPU.

In order to accomplish this I am attempting to launch a kernel using an N^2 set of blocks (where N in number of particles) using `(N/T, N/T)` grid and `T*T` blocks (where T is the number of threads per block). I have been able to launch an N*N grid but whenever I try to use multidimensional blocks (of threads) the kernel crashes with:

`error code invalid configuration arguments`

This is with T=512 and N=5000 but reducing these to T=128 and N=1000 had no effect.  Here are some specs and code:

***Cuda SDK Version: 7.5***

***GPU:  GTX 970 4gb***

***CC Version: 5.2***

***Compiling in MSVS 2013 64bit in Windows 7***

### Kernel Launch Code

```
dim3 block(TPB, TPB);
dim3 grid;
grid.x = (numParticles + TPB - 1) / TPB;
grid.y = (numParticles + TPB - 1) / TPB;

doParticles<<< grid, block >>>(d_pos, d_vel, d_acc, d_mass, numParticles, dt);
```

How can I change this code to accomplish my goal?

I can post some kernel code etc. but don't think it matters since the kernel doesn't even launch. Let me know if any other info would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

### MCVE

**main**

```
#define TPB 32
....

unsigned int numParticles = 1000;
p_type* h_pos;
p_type* h_vel;
p_type* h_acc;
p_type* h_mass;

p_type* d_pos;
p_type* d_vel;
p_type* d_acc;
p_type* d_mass;


int pointsPerParticleVec = 3;
size_t size = sizeof(p_type) * 3 * numParticles;

h_pos = (p_type*)malloc(size);
h_vel = (p_type*)malloc(size);
h_acc = (p_type*)malloc(size);
h_mass = (p_type*)malloc(size / 3);

d_pos = NULL;
d_vel = NULL;
d_acc = NULL;

cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
//allocate space on GPU
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pos, size);
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_vel, size);
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_acc, size);
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_mass, size / 3);

//nothing really matters for this example just making sure no gargage values happen
for (int partIt = 0; partIt < numParticles; partIt++)
{
    int index = partIt * 3;

    h_pos[index] = 0;
    h_pos[index + 1] = 0;
    h_pos[index + 2] = 0;

    h_vel[index] = 0;
    h_vel[index + 1] = 0;
    h_vel[index + 2] = 0;

    h_acc[index] = 0;
    h_acc[index + 1] = 0;
    h_acc[index + 2] = 0;

    h_mass[partIt] = 0;
}

err = cudaMemcpy(d_pos, h_pos, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
err = cudaMemcpy(d_vel, h_vel, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
err = cudaMemcpy(d_acc, h_acc, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
err = cudaMemcpy(d_mass, h_mass, size / 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

while (true)    //display functionality removed for now
{
    //do calculations
    float dt = .1;
    dim3 block(TPB, TPB);
    dim3 grid;
    grid.x = (numParticles + TPB - 1) / TPB;
    grid.y = (numParticles + TPB - 1) / TPB;

    doParticles << < grid, block >> >(d_pos, d_vel, d_acc, d_mass, numParticles, dt);   //<<<<<<<<<<<<here is where it does not launch

    err = cudaGetLastError();

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to launch vectorAdd kernel (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));   //see the error pop up here
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int numBlocks2 = (numParticles * 3 + TPB - 1) / TPB;

    //add acceleration to velocity
    ARR_ADD << <numBlocks2, TPB >> >(d_vel, d_acc, numParticles * 3);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //reset acceleration vector 
    ARR_SET << <numBlocks2, TPB >> >(d_acc, 0.0f, numParticles * 3);

    //add velocity to position
    POS_ADD << <numBlocks2, TPB >> >(d_pos, d_vel, numParticles * 3, dt);

    //copy vector back to cpu (until opengl-cuda gets implemented)
    cudaMemcpy(h_pos, d_pos, sizeof(p_type) * 3 * numParticles, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

**kernels**

```
__device__ float fInvSqrt_D(const float& in)
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = in * 0.5F;
    y = in;
    i = *(long *)&y;
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1);
    y = *(float *)&i;
    y = y * (threehalfs - (x2 * y * y));
    y = y * (threehalfs - (x2 * y * y));    //extra precision
    return abs(y);
}

__global__ void POS_ADD(p_type* getter, const p_type *giver, int N, float dt)
{
    int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < N)
    {
        getter[index] = getter[index] + (giver[index]*dt);
    }

}

__global__ void ARR_ADD(p_type* getter, const p_type *giver, int N)
{
    int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < N)
    {
        getter[index] = getter[index] + giver[index];
    }

}

__global__ void ARR_SET(p_type* getter, const p_type value, int N)
{
    int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < N)
    {
        getter[index] = value;
    }
}



__global__ void doParticles(p_type* pos, p_type* vel, p_type* acc, p_type* mass, int numParticles, float tstep)
{
    int blockId = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    int threadIndex = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    int cRowPos = blockId % gridDim.y;
    int notInRow = blockId - cRowPos;

    int Y = blockId/gridDim.x + threadIdx.y;    //slower changing iterator
    int X = threadIndex - ((notInRow) * TPB);   //fast changing iterator

    int pIndex1 = X * 3;
    int pIndex2 =Y * 3;

    if (pIndex1 != pIndex2 && Y < numParticles)
    {

        p_type diffx = (pos[pIndex1] - pos[pIndex2]);           //calculating difference between points
        p_type diffy = (pos[pIndex1 + 1] - pos[pIndex2 + 1]);
        p_type diffz = (pos[pIndex1 + 2] - pos[pIndex2 + 2]);

        p_type distsqr = diffx*diffx + diffy*diffy + diffz*diffz;

        if (distsqr < 0)
        {
            distsqr *= -1;
        }
        if (distsqr < 500)
        {
            distsqr = 500;
        }

        p_type attraction = (mass[X] * mass[Y]) / (distsqr);    //gravity equation


        p_type invsqrt = fInvSqrt_D((float)distsqr);
        p_type normx = invsqrt*diffx;
        p_type normy = invsqrt*diffy;
        p_type normz = invsqrt*diffz;

        p_type forcex = normx * -attraction;
        p_type forcey = normy * -attraction;
        p_type forcez = normz * -attraction;

        acc[pIndex1] += (forcex * tstep) / mass[X];
        acc[pIndex1 + 1] += (forcey * tstep) / mass[X];
        acc[pIndex1 + 2] += (forcez * tstep) / mass[X];


    }
}
```

And yes, I know the indexing in the doParticle kernel is broken. I plan on fixing that one it launches. :)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA thread blocks are limited to a maximum of 1024 threads,  The total threads in the block is the product of the threadblock dimensions:

```
dim3 block(TPB, TPB);
```

So any value of `TPB` larger than 32 here is not going to work, and you will get an invalid configuration argument error when you try to launch any such kernel.

So reduce `T` or `TPB` to 32 and you should be able to launch your kernel.

Comment: 32 does not work.  16 does though. I did notice before that I could only launch 512 threads even in one dimension instead of 1024 maybe that is playing a part in this discrepancy.

Comment: You can certainly launch a block of 32x32 threads on a GTX 970 on CUDA 7.5.  Since you haven't posted a complete code, I can't tell you what the issue is with 32x32 in your case.

Comment: What part of the code would you need to see? I could link a github but that isn't usually preferred. Or is it?

Comment: SO expects an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for questions like this.

Comment: Alright I added a MCVE should have everything you need. I appreciate your help.

Comment: For me, your kernel launches now.  You have other issues that are preventing the kernel from completing correctly, but its launching with 32x32 threads.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/wbxiSehn) is a complete demonstration that the kernel is launching without error, with 32x32 threadblock.  To be clear, I'm not saying your kernel runs to completion without error, but it *launches* with a 32x32 threadblock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111955/discussion-between-nathan-j-and-robert-crovella).